# Should the package contain unit tests/ test classes when the software has been passed to a client? JAVA

Tags: java, unit-testing, testing, junit

I got asked an interesting question that I didn't know the answer to.
Should the package contain unit tests/ test classes when the software has been passed to a client?

I think that assert statements can be disabled so technically you could disable the asserts before giving the software to the client. Is this correct?

Thanks in advance.

Comment: Just for the records: The native java `assert` statement that you can *turn on* by the JVMs `-ea` / `-enableassertions` swich has nothing to do with *UnitTests*.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

You should never deliver (unit) tests into a productive environment.

If you want to provide a test library for your clients (programmers/customers that use your apis), thats fine. It should not be included in the main artifacts that goes into production.

The reasoning behind this is: it reduces the attackable surface. Tests tend to ignore/circumvent security measures. Having them arround in production is just too risky for no benefit.

Comment: Thanks for your answer @k5_  What does "it reduces the attackable surface mean?"

Comment: "Attackable surface" basically means amount of errors or possiblities for somebody to break your program. Assuming that code contains about equal amount of errors per line. So the more lines of code you have the more errors you have. By reducing the amount of code in production you reduce the amount of errors. Also in my experience code qualitity in tests is quite poor so the amount of errors per line is higher in tests.

Answer (score 0):

I disagree with the other answer; as the true answer is: it **depends**.

More precisely it depends on the **contract** that you have with your client. If you wrote that piece of software for them; of course, everything that you did for that task most likely belongs to **them**. Including all kinds of project/setup/testing source code.

If we are talking about you offering some product that offers can use; it still depends.

k5_ is correct - unit tests should not be installed/executable within the production environment where your product is used. But: it might still be beneficial for the customer to receive (*some*!) of your unit tests. It might help to better understand how your application is working. They don't put it on their server; but their developers can have a look into your tests if needed.

But I agree; that last point is rather unusual; you might rather some tests as part of your documentation that is given to the customer.

Long story short: the important aspect here is to understand the exact details "where" those unit tests go to; and in what way they might be used.

Answer (score 0):

A production package should never contain unit tests. However, what you deliver to the client when you deliver the software is usually the source code, often the full repository, instead of just production package: that will, of course, contain the unit tests as well. They are an important part of the deliverable.

> I think that assert statements can be disabled so technically you
>   could disable the asserts before giving the software to the client. Is
>   this correct?

Java language asserts can be disabled. However, java assert statements are not related to junit asserts done in unit tests. Asserts in unit tests are not disabled in the same way, unit tests are just not packaged into the product when it is installed to running environment.